# Android application to RTL (Arabic)

Tags: android-development, applications, internationalization, languages

I have an Android application (**E-commerce**) in English, Now I want to change language to **Arabic** and **RTL**(Right to Left)

- I am new in that, where and how much efforts it take?
- What specific problems should I look out for?

Comment: Hello.  Welcome to Software Engineering.  I made some small changes to your question to hopefully make it a little easier to read.  If this was incorrect, please press [edit] and either rollback the edits or make additional ones.

Comment: For what it's worth, I disagree with the down voter.  This question is still pretty broad, but essentially it's "how do I do i18n, particularly with an RTL language?".

Comment: Thank you for the support, yes how do I do i18n - if necessary i can share app demo too. and application web code is build up in Magento 2

Comment: Yes i have whole Application(fully developed) In English now i want to convert in Arabic with RTL

Comment: And just for information - i have multi-language in store front in web.

Comment: We don't get into the code specifics here - see the [on-topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of [help], particularly the bit about [Why are implementation and debugging questions off-topic on Software Engineering?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7864/64132)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i have done in my app:

- fix layout. If you use the newest android studio the function "Analyse/Inspect-Code" provides warning if you for example use layout_alignParentRight (rtl independant) without layout_alignParentEnd (rtl dependant)
- Make shure that all text are put into string resource files (app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml for the english text). Then copy this file to app\src\main\res\values-ar\strings.xml and let somboedy translate it to arabic. Use a texteditor that can handle mixed rtl/non-rtl text if you have arabic text with english placeholders. I use notepad++ with option set "enforce rtl".